# Linking using map file without having object files

Tags: linker, operating-system, embedded, elf, linker-scripts

I want to create an operating system for embedded device with very limited resources (an ESP8266) that can load `ELF` files as program or shared object (shared object is in second importance).

I want to know is it possible to link any program for this OS against `map file` of OS?

for example I implement `memcpy` in OS and make a header file that declares it as `extern`, Compile OS and generate map file. then when i want to write a program, include the header to compile it successfully and make linker to peek the address of `memcpy` from map file of OS.

the OS is place non-independent and its functions are always at a fixed address, but programs are place independent ELF files. it is not necessary to program be loadable for different builds of OS.

Comment: What toolchain are you using?  They're all a little different.

Comment: Gnu toolchain, of course. ld from binutils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by no means a complete solution to the problem of running ELFs on a embedded target but for the specific problem of providing known addresses during the linking process, GNU LD allows you to provide addresses for symbols in code defined as extern by adding a `PROVIDE` statement or a simple assignment to the linker script. LD won't directly read a map file, but you could parse the map file, find the relevant addresses, generate a linker script that has the appropriate symbols provided, and use that linker script in the compilation of the ELF. The documentation for the provide and assignment features can be found at https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Assignments.html